# How to call Outlook after clicking a button in Java Swing?

Tags: java, outlook

I developed a desktop application in Java Swing. When I click a button, I want to open Microsoft Outlook. I am unable to figure it out to do this. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use the `Desktop` class to `open(File)` for which Outlook is the default consumer.  Or as pointed out by @Guillaume use [`Dekstop.mail()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail--) (or the overloaded variant) specifically for the email client.

Comment: wouln't `mail()` be a better choice? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail()

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Much better, so much better that ..forget what I said, go with `mail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this method:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command)
```