# Open excel sheet from JButton - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, excel

I'm designing a form using swing.If report button was clicked in my form it have to open the predefined format excel sheet from my D drive.What code have to write in button action listener ??

Thanks ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Outlook after clicking a button in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483805/how-to-call-outlook-after-clicking-a-button-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend looking at the Desktop class in awt.  There's a method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) that should help you.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("c:\\appNominalJournalFix.txt");
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really?  I put this in a main method and it works fine.  I'll paste the entire class but for me I'm certain it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Runtime` class to open the excel using the default program in `Windows`

```
String filePath = "D:\\test.xls";
Process p = 
  Runtime.getRuntime()
   .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filePath);
```

You can also use `Desktop` API as below.

```
String filePath = "D:\\test.xls";
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File(filePath));
```

Comment: Yep, This won't work except in windows. In linux, openoffice or libreoffice are used and rundll32 isn't found.